# Power automate - how to send email with attachment from request

Tags: c#, power-automate

I have this flow that accepts json (firstName, lastName, subject, email) and it works correctly.  Im planning to add to every email an attachment which will be coming from every request..

Im not sure what type should I use here.

[image]

this is also the c# code that im using to send/call this flow

[image]

how can I pass the file, should it be in byte format?

Comment: Read the array of bytes of your file in C# then try to convert the content of it in **base64**. And once received in Power Automate, decode the encoded string with the OOB function **decodeBase64()**. You'll match the json schema this way.

Comment: The above idea will work if your file is a text one. However, if it is a binary one, you should use **base64ToBinary()** in Power Automate and add the output in the attachment's content input textfield.